# Angular ngrx add/del returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-web-api, rxjs, ngrx

In my app I have a list of Vehicle IDs which I get from my web api.

The issue is that whenever I press my "add"-button to add an ID to my list it just adds a "undefined" to it. Whenever I'm just using my plain service and subscribe to it inside my add method it works fine. Same goes for my delete method.

Below I present the effect and reducer from ngrx store, my service, and my add/del function.

```
//ngrx/store/effect
  @Injectable()
export class FavVehiclesIdEffects {
  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private vehicleService: VehicleService
  ) {}

  @Effect()
  loadFavVehiclesId$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(favVehiclesIdAction.LOAD_FAVVEHICLES_ID)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.vehicleService.getFavourite().pipe(
          map(
            favVehiclesId =>
              new favVehiclesIdAction.LoadFavVehiclesIdSuccess(favVehiclesId)
          ),
          catchError(error =>
            of(new favVehiclesIdAction.LoadFavVehiclesIdFail(error))
          )
        );
      })
    );

  @Effect()
  addFavVehiclesId$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(favVehiclesIdAction.ADD_FAVVEHICLES_ID)
    .pipe(
      map((action: favVehiclesIdAction.AddFavVehiclesId) => action.payload),
      switchMap(favvehiclesid => {
        return this.vehicleService.addVehicle(favvehiclesid).pipe(
          map(
            favvehicleid =>
              new favVehiclesIdAction.AddFavVehiclesIdSuccess(favvehicleid)
          ),
          catchError(error =>
            of(new favVehiclesIdAction.AddFavVehiclesIdFail(error))
          )
        );
      })
    );

  @Effect()
  deleteFavVehiclesId$ = this.actions$
    .ofType(favVehiclesIdAction.DELETE_FAVVEHICLES_ID)
    .pipe(
      map((action: favVehiclesIdAction.DeleteFavVehiclesId) => action.payload),
      switchMap(favvehiclesid => {
        return this.vehicleService.deleteVehicle(favvehiclesid).pipe(
          map(
            () =>
              new favVehiclesIdAction.DeleteFavVehiclesIdSuccess(favvehiclesid)
          ),
          catchError(error =>
            of(new favVehiclesIdAction.DeleteFavVehiclesIdFail(error))
          )
        );
      })
    );
}
```

---

```
//ngrx/store/reducer
export interface FavVehiclesIdState {
  entities: { [id: number]: Tracker };
  loaded: boolean;
  loading: boolean;
}

export const initialState: FavVehiclesIdState = {
  entities: {},
  loaded: false,
  loading: false
};

export function reducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: fromFavVehiclesId.FavVehiclesIdAction
): FavVehiclesIdState {
  switch (action.type) {
    case fromFavVehiclesId.LOAD_FAVVEHICLES_ID: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true
      };
    }
    case fromFavVehiclesId.LOAD_FAVVEHICLES_ID_SUCCESS: {
      const favvehiclesid = action.payload;
      const entities = favvehiclesid.reduce(
        (entity: { [id: number]: Tracker }, favvehicleid: Tracker) => {
          return {
            ...entity,
            [favvehicleid.id]: favvehicleid
          };
        },
        {
          ...state.entities
        }
      );

      return {
        ...state,
        loaded: true,
        loading: false,
        entities
      };
    }
    case fromFavVehiclesId.LOAD_FAVVEHICLES_ID_FAIL: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loaded: false,
        loading: false
      };
    }

    case fromFavVehiclesId.ADD_FAVVEHICLES_ID_SUCCESS: {
      const favvehiclesid = action.payload;
      const entities = {
        ...state.entities,
        [favvehiclesid.id]: favvehiclesid
      };

      return {
        ...state,
        entities
      };
    }

    case fromFavVehiclesId.DELETE_FAVVEHICLES_ID_SUCCESS: {
      const favvehiclesid = action.payload;
      const { [favvehiclesid.id]: removed, ...entities } = state.entities;
      return {
        ...state,
        entities
      };
    }
  }
  return state;
}

export const getFavVehiclesIdEntities = (state: FavVehiclesIdState) =>
  state.entities;
export const getFavVehiclesIdLoaded = (state: FavVehiclesIdState) =>
  state.loaded;
export const getFavVehiclesIdLoading = (state: FavVehiclesIdState) =>
  state.loading;
```

---

```
//services.ts
getFavourite(): Observable<Tracker[]> {
    const url = `${this.API_URL}/favourites`;
    return this.http.get<Tracker[]>(url).pipe(
      tap(() => this.log(`fetched favVehicles id`)),
      catchError(this.handleError('getVehicles', []))
    );
  }

// Service for "add to favourite" button
  addVehicle(track: Tracker): Observable<Tracker> {
    const url = `${this.API_URL}/favourites`;
    const service = this.http.post<Tracker>(url, track, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`adding vehicle id=${track.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Tracker>('addVehicle'))
    );
    console.log(service);
    return service;
  }

  // Service for "delete from favourite" button
  deleteVehicle(track: Tracker): Observable<Tracker> {
    const url = `${this.API_URL}/favourites`;
    const service = this.http.put<Tracker>(url, track, this.httpOptions).pipe(
      tap(_ => this.log(`deleted vehicle id=${track.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Tracker>('deleteVehicle'))
    );
    console.log(service);
    return service;
  }
```

---

```
 // component.ts
 addFav(event: VehicleDetail) {

      const temp = new Tracker();
      temp.id = event.id;

      // adding to json file
      this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.AddFavVehiclesId(temp));

      this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadFavVehiclesId());

    }
  }
  // Button function which deletes the selected vehicle from your favourites
  deleteFav(event: VehicleDetail, text: string) {
      const temp = new Tracker();
      temp.id = event.id;

      // deleting from json file
      this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.DeleteFavVehiclesId(temp));

      this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadFavVehiclesId());

    }
  }
```

My get method works fine and have never been a problem. I have been wondering if my mapping I do (I take a "VehicleDetail" and remove its ID into my Tracker type, which is a object with only the property "id") causes some issues, and I have tried some variants, but overall Im quite lost since I followed along in a tutorial.
My JSON file gets updated correctly, so I believe the problem in somewhere in my ngrx store.  What is wrong here?
If you want me to clarify something please let me know.

#### Update

[image]

My entries are set to undefined. Is there anyone who have noticed something wrong with my reducer file?

My Tracker is presented below to make everything slightly more clear:

```
export class Tracker {
  id: number;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your reducer code?

Comment: @RenéWinkler Of course. Its updated!

Comment: @RenéWinkler You see anything in particular that looks odd?

Comment: I think basically it is ok. Your naming is very irritating and the reducer is too complicated. Have a look at ngrx/entity, this will make it much easier, more understandable and thus less error-prone. Have you installed the redux devtools? Maybe this will show xou some insights...

Comment: Thanks for your reply @RenéWinkler . I have updated the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your logic in the reducer for adding a vehicle should look like the following:

```
case fromFavVehiclesId.ADD_FAVVEHICLES_ID_SUCCESS: {
  const favvehiclesid = action.payload;
  const entities = [...state.entities, favvehiclesid];
  return {
    ...state,
    entities
  };
}
```

Comment: Im sorry but whenever I try this I get the following error: https://i.gyazo.com/0aea8bebed6a725b6cecbf2eae7dd30c.png

Is there a way I can avoid to change the type? Since the rest of the reducer builds upon this idea.

Comment: The entities is defined in the following manner:   entities: { [id: number]: Tracker }; I use this because my selector is using the IDs to return all "FavVehiclesId". https://i.gyazo.com/b0e9e3843bca7720ddf56fe0875b54d2.

Comment: All seems quite fine to me. But why you are reloading all vehicles after you have added or deleted one in your component. can you remove the this.store.dispatch(new fromStore.LoadFavVehiclesId()); from the addFav and delteFav method.

Comment: I did this because I wanted to reload the array of the vehicles im displaying in the list so you can see the updated view. Yeah I dont really know what the issue is.. The get method works completly fine. Its just the add/del that causes this problem.

Comment: Sorry I dont know, bit if I were you I would start again with ngrx entity, this makes he whole stuff a lot easier.

Comment: I finally solved it. The misstake I did was that I returned a list of "Tracker"s from my web api instead of a single "Tracker". This caused confusion since the program didn't know what ID to associate it with. Thanks for helping me out bud.